# How to install Hmisc package? (Line 108(chunk 10) package 'Hmisc' could not be loaded)

Tags: r

I am trying to run the below code in R Studio. I am unable to install Hmisc package. You may ask me for more info about something and I will reply. Windows 11, R 4.3.2 and RStudio is the latest version, Here is the code:

> install.packages("UsingR", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

> install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

> library("UsingR")

> install.packages("tidyverse", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")

> library("tidyverse")

> library("viridis")

The error:

> (Line 108(chunk 10) package 'Hmisc' could not be loaded)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). FWIW, your question does not help us in answering the following questions which can drastically increase your (and future readers') chances to resolve the issue: What kind of error do you get when you try to install `Hmisc`? What is your operating system? What version of R are you using? Is your RStudio up-to-date?

Comment: @medium-dimensional Windows 11, R 4.3.2 and RStudio is the latest version,

Comment: Please add this information directly to the post along with the error you get: no screenshot/image of the errors please. You can directly post the code as well the corresponding error using [fenced code blocks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/7789963).

Comment: What happens when you try: `install.packages("Hmisc")` and then `library(Hmisc)`?

Comment: When you run `install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`, what prints on the console? Does *that line* get an error?

Comment: Also, from the `Line 108 (Chunk 10)` part you post, it sounds like this is inside an Rmarkdown or Quarto document. I would suggest **not installing packages** inside such documents, as that will attempt to re-download and re-install the package every time the document is compiled. You certainly need the `library()` calls to **load already-installed packages**, but the `install.packages()` lines should be done separately, just in your console really, as installation only needs to be done successfully 1 time.

Comment: @medium-dimensional I tried this :


> install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")


library(Hmisc)

Comment: @medium-dimensional Here is the error: Line 108(chunk 10) package or namespace load failed for 'Hmisc' in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):

Comment: @GregorThomas Yep I just tried that. Reload to see the error.

Comment: That sounds like an error from the `library` line, not the `install.packages()` line. And also since it says "Line 108(chunk 10)` it sounds like you're running it in the document. I want you to go to your R console **not the document**, and **run only the line `install.packages("Hmisc")`** and tell us what happens.

Answer (score 0):

One can not load a package if it is not installed properly. So, please make sure the package `Hmisc` is installed properly. You can use [`.packages`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/zpackages.html) to check the package availability:

```
> "Hmisc" %in% .packages(all.available = T)
# Returns TRUE if Hmisc is installed
```

Installation of packages can fail because of many *unknown* causes. You need to understand what  specific cause is hindering the installation of the package in your system.

For example, if I run the following code in R console* on my computer:

```
> install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

I get the following error:

```r
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/Hmisc_5.1-1.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3556151 bytes (3.4 MB)
===========================
downloaded 1.8 MB

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  download from 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/Hmisc_5.1-1.tgz' failed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  downloaded length 0 != reported length 0
2: In download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) :
  URL 'http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/R/CRAN/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/Hmisc_5.1-1.tgz': Timeout of 60 seconds was reached
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘Hmisc’ failed
```

If one just reads through the installation error, they might be curios to understand the phrase `Timeout of 60 seconds was reached`.

One then can see what this `Timeout` is in the context of `install.packages` by utilising the help operator [`?`](https://www.r-project.org/help.html) in R Console:

```
> ?install.packages
```

> ...
> ...
> Timeouts 
> A limit on the elapsed time for each call to R CMD INSTALL (so for source installs) can be set via environment variable *R_INSTALL_PACKAGES_ELAPSED_TIMEOUT*: in seconds (or in minutes or hours with optional suffix ‘⁠m⁠’ or ‘⁠h⁠’, suffix ‘⁠s⁠’ being allowed for the default seconds) with 0 meaning no limit.

The help call hints that setting *time limit* to 0 might be helpful if the installation procedure needs more than just 60 seconds to install the package.** But how do I inform the function call to set no time limit for installation? From the output of `?install.packages` related to `Timeout`, I see that a phrase 'environment variable' might be helpful to know more about.

A quick search on the internet with "environment variable timeout in r" and couple of clicks here and there took me to the base function [`options`](https://web.mit.edu/%7Er/current/arch/i386_linux26/lib/R/library/base/html/options.html). I searched if `options` can help me change the time limit by looking at anything that resembled to "timeout" or "time limit". `options` indeed allows to set an argument `timeout`:

> ...
> ...
> timeout: 
> positive integer. The timeout for some Internet operations, in seconds. Default 60 (seconds) but can be set from environment variable R_DEFAULT_INTERNET_TIMEOUT. (Invalid values of the option or the variable are silently ignored: non-integer numeric values will be truncated.) See download.file and connections.

Perfect. Then I tried:

```
> options(timeout = 5 * 60) # setting time limit to 5 minutes
> install.packages("Hmisc", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

No error was generated and `Hmisc` was successfully installed:

> trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/macosx/big-sur-arm64/contrib/4.3/Hmisc_5.1-1.tgz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3556151 bytes (3.4 MB)
> ==================================================
> downloaded 3.4 MB
>
> The downloaded binary packages are in
> /var/folders/dx/#########

Then I tried `library(Hmisc)` which led to successful loading of `Hmisc` in to the current workspace:

> Attaching package: ‘Hmisc’
>
> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>
> format.pval, units

---

*R console can be accessed inside R Studio: Go to `View > Move Focus To Console`. See [this set of instructions](https://docs.posit.co/ide/user/ide/guide/ui/ui-panes.html) to see where it is located in R Studio.

**If you are located in a country other than USA, you can also try that country's [CRAN mirror](https://cran.r-project.org/) manually after running:

```
> install.packages("Hmisc")
```